# Removing signs from a Shul bulletin board

Tags: halacha, synagogue, business

In many areas Shuls have a bulletin board on which signs are hung. In some larger cities there are sign hanging companies that for a fee, go around and hang up posters for businesses on these bulletin boards. May one remove a sign from the bulletin board at any time? Is there any prohibition involved in removing a sign? The advertiser paid the hanging company however does not pay the Shul anything for the privilege of having the sign hanging in the Shul. (a sourced answer would be appreciated)

Comment: I think the answer should be obvious, though I don't have a source. It's the prerogative of the Shul to allow or remove such signs, and competing advertisers, without the backing of the Shul, might be interfering with their competition if they remove their signs. If it's been up for months, it might be ok to post yours over theirs. But you should probably just ask the Shul if it's alright to remove some old ones to make room for new ones.

Comment: If the sign is offensive (to the community, not to you personally), then by all means take it down. If it's slanderous, take it down. If it's political, the Shul probably doesn't want to be seen as endorsing some party/candidate/issue (unless you know otherwise), and would probably be ok with you taking it down.

Comment: What are the Shul's rules about the board?

Comment: @DoubleAA: There are no rules.

Comment: @GershonGold 1) I don't believe you. 2) How could you possibly do anything wrong?

Comment: I've seen many shuls that "freely" allow anyone to post anything at all. (It's a problem - clutter for one.) I don't think anyone really has the permission to remove the sign other than someone in charge of the shul or the bulletin board. They can devise whatever rules they want, and I don't think they need to inform anyone of them. I.e. - I think it's understood that if they allow you to put up a sign, the shul can remove it, and if anyone else removes it (rightfully or not) the shul is not responsible in any way. A good shul has a glass-locked board. Thus, only the shul posts signs.